# How shall I understand what the GNU utilities "comm" and "diff" do in terms of ordered sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, algorithms, computer-science, order-theory

I am looking for some help  to understand two GNU utility programs in terms of ordered sets. If you happen to know their usages, you might be able to understand what I am asking here.

In mathematics, a set doesn't impose order between its elements. (if a set does, then it is called an ordered set, a different concept)

- the difference operation on two sets results in a set of the elements in the first set but not in the second.
- When taking the intersection of two sets, if an element is considered in both sets, it doesn't matter where it appears in each set.

Similar operations to set difference exist on files, such as [`comm` from coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#comm-invocation) and [`diff` from diffutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/diffutils.html#toc-diff-Output-Formats).  But we can't think of a file as a set of lines, but as an ordered set of lines, because the lines are ordered by their line numbers naturally.

Moreover, `comm` and `diff` also work differently from each other.

What do `comm` and `diff` try to accomplish at concept level (at input and output level) respectively? I suspect I may need some basic knowledge on ordered sets to understand that. I don't expect an explanation at their implementation/algorithmic level, but that might help (I heard that version control is using same algorithms to accomplish incremental copy.)

Specifically, given two files, for each line in each  file, how do [`comm`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#comm-invocation) and [`diff`](https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/diffutils.html#toc-diff-Output-Formats) determine

- whether the line also occur in the other file?
- if it does, whether its occurrences in the two files are the same or different?

by taking into account the order between the lines in each file?

How  does `diff` decide whether some line "occurs in both files but differ" or "occurs in one file but not the other"?

How do `comm` and `diff`  differ when both are used for taking subtraction of two files?

Thanks.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

$\mathtt{comm}$ does a set operation on two sets of text lines on the assumption that the two sets are represented as sorted input files, so it can work through both sequences deciding which lines are in file 1 only, which are in file 2 only and which are in both without having to backtrack.

$\mathtt{diff}$ is quite different. It takes two text files and tries to find an efficient way of describing the second file as a result of editing the first. This is a loosely defined problem. $\mathtt{diff}$ uses some form of the [longest common subsequence algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) to solve it. The results can be counter-intuitive.

Comment: Thanks. As far as my question are concerned, I don't require comm to work on sorted files only.

Comment: The documentation for $\mathtt{comm}$ is quite clear that the input files must be sorted. What $\mathtt{comm}$ does on input files that are not sorted is implementation defined: it could produce an error message, or crash or deliver an arbitrary output.

Comment: Thanks. The LCS algorithm explains how diff decides if a line exists in one file but not in the other. How does diff decide whether a line occurs in both files but differ (indicated by "!" in context mode of diff, "fct" i.e. replacement in normal mode of diff, and "|" in side by side mode of diff)

Comment: A second question: when comm operates on two sorted files, does it also generate the same result as LCS algorithm applies to the sorted files?

Comment: For your first question: In addition to finding the LCS diff has to keep track of which position in the original strings each line comes from. So diff 'A B C D E' with itself yields "lines 1-5 = lines 1-5", while diff "A B C D E" with "A B X D E" yields "lines 1-2 = lines 1-2" + "lines 4-5 = lines 4-5". The gap in both sequences shows that a line has changed.

Comment: a third question: is the algorithm which comm implements a greedy algorithm (and thus the problem it solves is a matroid optimization problem)? I suspect it is, because it doesn't backtrack?

Comment: The assumptions made by $\mathtt{comm}$ are outside your control. Because the two input files are assumed to be sorted, the algorithm for $\mathtt{comm}$ involves a simple linear pass through the two files, nothing like as complicated as the matroid optimization problem. There is no need for backtracking because if the current lines from the two files are different, you know the line that comes first in the ordering cannot be common to both files.

Comment: ... and I don't think matroids would be relevant even if you did wnat to implement a variant of $\mathtt{comm}$ that didn't require sorted inputs.What you'd need is an efficient way of representing the multisets corresponding to the lines in the two files. In practice, sorting the input files and then doing what $\mathtt{comm}$ does looks like a very good approach to me.

Comment: @JonathanZ Thanks. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/480848/how-does-diff-decide-whether-a-difference-is-change-i-e-replacement-or-comb

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about `comm`, but the math name for what `diff` figures out is "longest common subsequence". If you search using that term you will find tons of information about it; maybe start with the Wikipedia article.

Although you do have to think about it kind of backwards, as the output of `diff` consists of all the parts that aren't in the longest common subsequence.

Also, as to terminology, "ordered sets" isn't quite right, after all $\mathbb{R}$ is an ordered set. I'd describe them as (finite) sequences.

Comment: Minor point: you need to be careful as the idea of "longest common subsequence" is loosely specified as it stands. E.g., 12345678 and 56781234 have two longest common subsequences.  (I did once work on a project  where the user interface programmers implemented the algorithm one way and the programmers working on the back-end implemented it another way $\ddot{\smile}$.)

Comment: I'm just surprised that your interface team implemented LCS.